# How to execute dynamic stored procedure in sql server with boolean return value?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sp-executesql, output-parameter

I have a stored procedure that has boolean result parameter as output. But my project needs to use 3 databases. Basically, there is a main database and 2 others. The other databases using same stored procedure but they just depend on params. If I explain the scenario, you will understand. Firstly, Sorry for bad explaining.

This application using main database for session management, user configurations and so on. This is okay. The problem is same user has to use 2 different databases for creating invoices. We can pretend that these users are IT support staff. They works for 2 different companies and supporting their products and they are managing their solutions in different databases.

> > User
> >
> > > > Main Database
> > > >
> > > > > > A Company Data
> > > > > >
> > > > > > B Company Data

Users have to create their invoices for each company's customers. Basically they are using same database but the name of databases are totally different. Maybe my problem has easier solution so I want to ask that **How can I use Dynamic Database Name in my Stored Procedure?** and my current question is I'm initialising Stored Procedure as String and after that I execute the stored procedure as String.

Procedure has no error, also says me completed successfully but there is no insert (in stored procedure). When I use the sql command (which I set manually as String) in Management Studio, Query is running perfectly.

**As a summary,**

I have 3 databases, Main database need to execute generating Invoice stored procedure. But database names are must be dynamic because of different companies.

When I send the database name A_COMPANY_DB, stored procedure should execute in A_COMPANY_DB. When I send B_COMPANY_DB, stored procedure should execute B_COMPANY_DB.

Both of A_COMPANY and B_COMPANY databases are same. I have to manage sql query as String because of Dynamic Database Name. So I can't reach the output parameter.

My stored procedure has only one output parameter which is bit type. But I can't use it like:

```
    Set @dynsql = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DbName) + ' exec.[dbo].[spName] ' + other params

EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynsql
```

In this situation I couldn't reach Output parameter. How can I set or use my Output parameter in this stored procedure?

`EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynsql @outputparam OUT`

Is it possible or any solution?

Sorry for bad explaining.

Comment: Does your databases lies in same server ?

Comment: Yes, they are located in same server.